# UpperCase no CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-jpa

Tenho a seguinte consulta com CriteriaBuilder

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Escola> cq = cb.createQuery(Escola.class);

    Root<Escola> root = cq.from(Escola.class);
    cq.select(root);
    List<Predicate> filtros = new ArrayList<>();

    if(filtro!=null) {
        if(filtro.getCnpj() != null && !filtro.getCnpj().isEmpty() ) {
            Path<String> campoCnpj = root.<String>get("cnpj");
            Predicate filtroCnpj =  cb.like(campoCnpj, "%"+filtro.getCnpj()+"%" ) ;  //(Predicate) cb.like(campoRazaoSocial , "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial().toLowerCase()+"%"); 
            filtros.add(filtroCnpj) ;
        }

        if(filtro.getRazaoSocial() != null && !filtro.getRazaoSocial().isEmpty() ) {
            Path<String> campoRazaoSocial = root.<String>get("razaoSocial");
            Predicate filtroRazaoSocial =  cb.like(campoRazaoSocial, "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial()+"%" ) ;  //(Predicate) cb.like(campoRazaoSocial , "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial().toLowerCase()+"%"); 
            filtros.add(filtroRazaoSocial) ;
        }

        cq.where(filtros.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }



    TypedQuery<Escola> tq = manager.createQuery(cq);
    return tq.getResultList();
```

Funciona, mas gostaria que filtro não fizesse diferenciação entre maiúsculas e minusculas.

Na linha do Predicate (abaixo) eu até consigo colocar o toUpperCase no campo de filtro. 
**Mas como faço para fazer o mesmo no campo de Path?**

```
Path<String> campoRazaoSocial = root.<String>get("razaoSocial");
Predicate filtroRazaoSocial =  cb.like(campoRazaoSocial, "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial()+"%" ) ;  //(Predicate) cb.like(campoRazaoSocial , "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial().toUpperCase()+"%");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quem interessar possa

para fazer o upper basta fazer como no exemplo abaixo.

**Sem o upperCase**

```
Predicate filtroRazaoSocial =  cb.like(campoRazaoSocial, "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial()+"%" ) ;
```

**Como o upperCase**

```
Predicate filtroRazaoSocial =  cb.like(cb.upper(campoRazaoSocial), "%"+filtro.getRazaoSocial().toUpperCase()+"%" )
```